# Making object slide to one direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make my Rigidbody object slide to to right or left.

For example, if he's at 0 X, he'll slide 1 in a direction, then stop in this direction and stop.

By adding a force, the object keeps moving in that direction, I want the object to move, then stop.

**Edit**
This is what I've tried

```
void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("d") && !isMoving) {
        StartCoroutine(MoveToPos(Vector3.right));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("a") && !isMoving) {
        StartCoroutine(MoveToPos(Vector3.left));
    }
}

public IEnumerator MoveToPos(Vector3 direction) {
    isMoving = true;
    var t = 0f;
    var startPosition = transform.position;
    var value = direction == Vector3.right? 1 : -1;
    while (t < 1f) {
        t += 0.05f;
        var endPosition = transform.position;
        endPosition.x = startPosition.x + value * t;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, endPosition, t);
        Debug.Log(player.position);
        yield return null;
    }
    isMoving = false;
}
```

But sadly the animation of it is very ugly, the object snaps into the final position after little time, doesn't look like the object slides then stops there. Like there is no acceleration and deceleration.

**Edit 2**

I've tried tweaking the values and making a deceleration movement. Kinda worked, but I guess it still need improvement.

```
public IEnumerator MoveToPos(Vector3 direction) {
    isMoving = true;
    var t = 0.0;
    var startPosition = transform.position;
    var value = direction == Vector3.right ? 1 : -1;
    while (t < 1) {
        if (t < 0.5) t += 0.1;
        else t += 0.03125;
        Debug.Log(t);
        var endPosition = transform.position;
        endPosition.x = startPosition.x + value * (float)t;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, endPosition, (float)t);
        yield return null;
    }
    isMoving = false;
}
```

I'm guessing tweaking the values of the acceleration and deceleration would make the animation smoother.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is like that:

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 1);
    }
```

Being "A Key" your conditional to move the object, and changing `Vector3.right` for the correspondent direction (left, up, down...)

But I'll suggest to use Lerp function to give it more realistic movement:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: The Lerp function works with an IEnumerator, but sadly the movement is very ugly. The object slides to the position then snaps into the final position.

Comment: So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Something smooth. From start point to end point with acceleration and declaration.

Answer (score -1):

There are few mistakes in your code:

**1**. Do not increment the time (`t` variable) with a fixed number. Use `Time.deltaTime` for that.

**2**. Do not move a GameObject with Rigidbody with the `transform`. So, don't do `transform.position = xxx` or `transform.Translate(xxx)`. When moving a Rigidbody object, use the `Rigidbody.MovePosition` function.

**3**. *You should enable `isKinematic` on the Rigidbody when moving it with the `Rigidbody.MovePosition` function because it makes it very smooth.*

Finally, to make it stop right away after the movement is complete, set the `velocity` and `angularVelocity` to zero.

Your fixed new function:

```
bool isMoving = false;
IEnumerator MoveToPos(Rigidbody targetObject, Vector3 direction, float duration, float units = 1f)
{
    isMoving = true;
    targetObject.isKinematic = true;

    float counter = 0;

    //Get the current position of the object to be moved
    Vector3 startPos = targetObject.position;
    //Get destination position
    Vector3 toPosition = startPos + direction * units;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        //targetObject.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration);
        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration); ;
        targetObject.MovePosition(newPos);
        yield return null;
    }

    targetObject.isKinematic = false;
    //Stop right away
    targetObject.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    targetObject.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    isMoving = false;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
StartCoroutine(MoveToPos(rb, Vector3.right, 3f, 1f));
```

Comment: I didn't try this yet, but I would guess that the stopping is immediate, not physics basic. It would be good to find something that gives the object a small push, enough to make it reach the other side, while damping over time. Snapping the object into the end position is looking very ugly, like you pushed the object, but it got stuck and pinned midway.

Comment: *"Snapping the object into the end position"* No that's not what my code is doing. It finds the end position, divides it into pieces and smoothly lerps to each one. Do try what's in the answer before making further comments so that your comments will reflect to an actual problem you run into. If you want the slide to be controlled by the physics engine, add force to the direction: `Rigidbody.AddForce(direction * speed)`

Comment: The object slides on the X axis, but it froze on the other axes. My object is moving forward on the Z axis all the time, so freezing it on the other axes is a really bad move.